# React multiple http calls when navigating the application using the URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component which has filtering, searching and pagination capabilities. What I'm trying is to create a queryString and attach to the URL such that I can later copy and paste it in another browser so that I can reuse the filters.

To extract the query params from the URL I'm using the `useLocation` hook

```
const useQuery = () => new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
const pageNo = useQuery().get('page') ?? 1;
```

I'm using the `useEffect` hook to track for changes of the `page` query parameter value, and  dispatch an action which will update the `pageNo` in the `state` object of my reducer.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({
    type: actionDescriptor.CHANGE_PAGE,
    payload: pageNo
  });
}, [pageNo]);
```

I have another `useEffect` hook which handles the fetch of the data, and gets triggered when the `pageNo` changes. I'm using the `useNavigate` to create and navigate to the new location if the http call was successful

```
const nav = useNavigate();

React.useEffect(() => { 
  (async function get() {

     const response = // make http call and get response    

     if (response.status === 200) {
       dispatch({
         type: actionDescriptor.FETCH_SUCCESS,
         payload: {
           data: response.data['value'],
         }
       });

       nav (`/data?page=${state.pageNo}`);
     } 
     /// handle error
    }
  })();
}, [state.pageNo, state.pageSize, state.filter]);
```

When I'm navigating using the UI, selecting a different page for example, all works well, there is a single http call, the browser url is updated as expected (e.g. localhost/mydata?page=2). If however I'm copying the url and paste it in another window, it makes two http calls, and renders the dom twice. What might be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is due to the parameters you are listening on `state.pageNo, state.pageSize, state.filter`. I'm assuming all of these are null/empty at the beginning of your app. Once you copied and pasted the url, two of these parameters will change which will cause the useEffect to be called twice.

put in a console.log in the useEffect to confirm that. Once that's confirmed, I would re-examine the list of parameters to see if you need to listen to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the pageNo. It looks like it might be changing from default value to *2* since you have 2 useEffects probably firing for the same render.